# Sort data 'Abr/2017'

Tags: javascript

I need to sort my array, he is like this:

```
x = {
    'Abr/2017': [ { id: 1 } ],
    'Fev/2018': [ { id: 1 } ],
    'Jul/2017': [ { id: 1 } ],
    'Abr/2018': [ { id: 1 } ],
    'Fev/2017': [ { id: 1 } ],
    'Jul/2018': [ { id: 1 } ],
    'Dez/2019': [ { id: 1 } ]
}
```

and I need him to be sorted first in the year and then in the months

Comment: Objects have no order.

Comment: `x` is not an array, it's an object. Object key have no order.

Answer (score 0):

Because your data is represented as object, you have to convert it to array as a first step. Then you can sort. Later you can map result array to whatever you want.

Important thing is that if you want to keep this data in some order then you have to use array structure

```js
let x = {
  'Abr/2017': [ { id: 1 } ],
  'Fev/2018': [ { id: 1 } ],
  'Jul/2017': [ { id: 1 } ],
  'Abr/2018': [ { id: 1 } ],
  'Fev/2017': [ { id: 1 } ],
  'Jul/2018': [ { id: 1 } ],
  'Dez/2019': [ { id: 1 } ]
}
// this function transform your object to array representation 
// where your actual key (e.g. Fev/2017) is stored in helper 
// property called key
function toArray(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((arr, key) => {
    arr.push({ key, data: obj[key] })
    return arr
  }, [])
}

function byYearAndMonth() {
  // month definition - help with sorting
  let monthOrder = {
    'Jan': 1,
    'Fev': 2,
    'Mar': 3,
    'Abr': 4,
    'Mai': 5,
    'Jun': 6,
    'Jul': 7,
    'Ago': 8,
    'Set': 9,
    'Out': 10,
    'Nov': 11,
    'Dez': 12
  }
  let mapDate = function([month, year]) {
    return [monthOrder[month], Number(year)]
  }

  // actual sorting function
  return function(a, b) {
    const [aMonth, aYear] = mapDate(a.key.split('/'))
    const [bMonth, bYear] = mapDate(b.key.split('/'))
    if(aYear < bYear) {
      return -1
    }
    if(aYear > bYear) {
      return 1
    }
    if(aMonth < bMonth) {
      return -1
    }
    if(aMonth > bMonth) {
      return 1
    }
    return 0
  }
}

// lets try how it works
let xArray = toArray(x)
xArray.sort(byYearAndMonth());
var result = xArray.map(x => x) 
// with map (or reduce) you can transform it to whatever you want
// I'm just returning exactly the same object
console.log(result)
```